# Python - subprocess - getstatusoutput

Tags: python, subprocess, output

I'm new to Python and Programming as well. I know from Google's python class how to run external command using:

> (status, output) = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
>    if status:    ## Error case, print the command's output to stderr and exit
>      sys.stderr.write(output)
>      sys.exit(1)

But I perceive that *commands* module is going obsolete. I want the status and the output, so I can print the output using sys.stderr.write() if there is any error. So, is there any equivalent command in *subprocess* module? I'm currently using:

> subprocess.call(args,shell=False) now.

Thanks!

Comment: `subprocess.check_output` in a `try` block would be the closest equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

There is [`subprocess.getstatusoutput()` in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#legacy-shell-invocation-functions) that [could be implemented as](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/subprocess.py#l697):

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError, STDOUT

def getstatusoutput(cmd):
    try:
        data = check_output(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stderr=STDOUT)
        status = 0
    except CalledProcessError as ex:
        data = ex.output
        status = ex.returncode
    if data[-1:] == '\n':
        data = data[:-1]
    return status, data
```

Both return `status` that is different from the original `commands.getstatusoutput()`. See [Python Issue: Document & unittest the subprocess.getstatusoutput() status value](http://bugs.python.org/issue23508).

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to do this, with a bit less code

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def getstatusoutput(command):
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE)
    out, _ = process.communicate()
    return (process.returncode, out)

code, out = getstatusoutput(["echo", "some text"])
print code
print out
```

Answer (score 0):

[Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) is a nice and easy way to do it:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def local(command):
    print 'local', local
    process = Popen(command.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out = process.stdout.read()
    err = process.stderr.read()
    print 'out', out
    print 'err', err
    returncode = process.wait()
    if returncode:
        raise Exception(returncode, err)
    else:
        return out
```

Comment: your code deadlocks if the child process generates enough output to fill stderr's OS pipe buffer.

Answer (score 0):

What `getstatusoutput` does is gather both `stdout` and `stderr` output interleaved in one variable. This will quite closely replicate the *actual* behaviour of `getstatusoutput` on those where it does not exist (`getstatusoutput` and the whole `commands` module was removed on Python 3 completely), excepting the newline behaviour. The resulting data is in `bytes`.

```
def getstatusoutput(cmd):
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    out, _ = process.communicate()

    if out[-1:] == b'\n':
        out = out[:-1]

    return (process.returncode, out)
```

This function returns `bytes` on Python 3 on purpose, as the Python 2 version returns `str`

Comment: it does not replicate actual behavior: [you need to trim the newline (and return text on Python 3)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28483026/4279).